# How To Make A Video File From Images

Tags: c#, video

I would Like to Know how to make a video file from images.

The reason is I want to make a screen capture application.

I will be coding it in C# and Intend to Capture the Screen as a

Bitmap and then Write it to a file.

Don't tell me to use some library or DLL that I can download somewhere.

I want to know how to do it with the raw bytes.

Comment: 1. Read about different movie formats. 2. Implement said format writer that takes bitmaps and spits out movie file.

Comment: C# doesn't have video encoding built in, so you're going to have to use a library.

Comment: @Overv: He wants to do it on his own, which one can do in C# (it can after all manipulate files and memory :-) .  It's a lot of work though...

Comment: @EricJ. In that case he could save uncompressed video in an AVI container. I imagine that wouldn't be very complex.

Comment: Actually I don't have to use a Library... And I'm not looking for anything built in. I am planning on Writing the raw bytes directly to a file. I have already found out how to do the header but still don't know how to do the data chunks.

Comment: Depends on the format you want to write and what the specification for that format says it can handle. Some formats may take raw bitmap data and be fine with it but it's likely that some will want some level of compression.

Comment: @EricJ. Do you know how to write one from scratch?

Comment: Do you know which video format you want? Then get/buy the specifications of that format, read and understand them, then write your encoder.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to generate video with free library [NReco.VideoConverter](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx) (nuget package is also available) that actually is .NET wrapper for FFMpeg tool.

There are 2 ways how it is possible:

- If you already have image files the best way is using special "image2" format (FFMpeg demuxer) and FFMPeg will read files directly for producing video
- Video can be produced in real-time with live stream conversion supported by VideoConverter. In this case "rawvideo" should be specified as input format and C# application should pass RAW bitmap bytes (as mentioned in the question) as input for live stream converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this on your own (which I would not recommend), a relative easy way is to convert your rgb images to YCbCr colorspace and than write it in YUV4MPEG2 format: https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2
This can be saved as *.y4m files which can be opened e.g. by VLC.

Beware that this is going to be "uncompressed" and thus will result in huge files (you get a little compression if you choose to use YCbCr 4:2:2 or 4:2:0, but nowhere near a modern video encoding algorithm like H.264 would achieve).

Why don't you want to use a library? I have been down this road. Video compression or even understanding the container formats (if your unexperienced in the field) is a complex matter and, as I already said, I don't recommend it.

Comment: ups, I just realized that this question was asked some time ago..