# Nreco video converter make video from image sequence

Tags: c#, video-conversion

I'm trying to make a video from a sequence of .jpg files using Nreco.videoconverter ffmpeg wrapper. I search for answer on this forum and topic that almost help me is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280199/how-to-make-a-video-file-from-images
```

> If you already have image files the best way is using special
>   "image2" format (FFMpeg demuxer) and FFMPeg will read files directly
>   for producing video
>       Video can be produced in real-time with live stream conversion supported by VideoConverter. In this case "rawvideo" should be
>   specified as input format and C# application should pass RAW bitmap
>   bytes (as mentioned in the question) as input for live stream
>   converter.

I try with this code but I always get video with 1 frame (the first one from array):

```
NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter c = new FFMpegConverter();

                ConcatSettings set = new ConcatSettings();
                set.VideoFrameRate = 5;
                set.VideoFrameCount = 10;
                set.ConcatVideoStream = true;
                set.ConcatAudioStream = false;
                set.SetVideoFrameSize(704, 576);

                 string[] _fileNames = new string[25];
                _fileNames[0] = "g:\\Storage\\001.jpg";
                _fileNames[1] = "g:\\Storage\\002.jpg";
                _fileNames[2] = "g:\\Storage\\003.jpg";
                _fileNames[3] = "g:\\Storage\\004.jpg";
                _fileNames[4] = "g:\\Storage\\005.jpg";
                _fileNames[5] = "g:\\Storage\\006.jpg";
                _fileNames[6] = "g:\\Storage\\007.jpg";
                _fileNames[7] = "g:\\Storage\\008.jpg";
                _fileNames[8] = "g:\\Storage\\009.jpg";
                _fileNames[9] = "g:\\Storage\\010.jpg";

           c.ConcatMedia(_fileNames, "g:\\Storage\\test2.mp4", Format.mp4, set);
```

I also try to use ConvertMedia() method instead ConcatMedia but with same result.

Is there any way to tell converter this is a sequence of images ?

Is there any other FFMPEG wrraper or way to do this ?

I found AForge class which is good but working only with .NET 3.5

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

FFMpegConverter.ConcatMedia uses concat filter for merging several video files and should not be used for encoding video from images.

Correct way of using ConvertMedia method with ffmpeg image demuxer:

```
var videoConv = new FFMpegConverter();
videoConv.ConvertMedia( 
   @"g:\Storage\%03d.jpg", null, 
   "test.mp4", null, 
   new ConvertSettings() {
      CustomInputArgs = " -framerate 5 ",

      // specify any additional ffmpeg parameters for output here
      CustomOutputArgs = " -profile:v high " 
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i can set a duration for this converted video to last few second so i can see the image. Currently it is not even second long. hard to see the image in the video also.

Comment: I cant seem to get this working, is this a valid answer?

Comment: @MarkRedman yes it works; maybe your image files doesn't match %03d.jpg pattern?.. you may try to perform conversion from the command line first (with ffmpeg.exe) to see what is happening.

Comment: I have almost the same pattern and numbered images..

videoConverter.ConvertMedia(@"c:\temp\snapshots\%03d.jpg", null, "Video.mp4", null, new ConvertSettings() { CustomInputArgs = " -framerate 5 ", CustomOutputArgs = " -profile:v high " });

error:Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height (exit code: 1)

Comment: @MarkRedman it's hard to suggest anything just by this information. You may check official ffmpeg docs about encoding video from images: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: I tried out `NReco.VideoConverter` library and tried to compress/convert a sample video having 50mb size. But using this code (`var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();  ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(input, output, Format.mo4);` causes 100% cpu usage. Are there any workarounds ?

Comment: @zackraiyan what is wrong with this? Video encoding is rather CPU intensive task; by default ffmpeg tries to use all available cores to perform conversion as fast as possible. You can limit number of threads with ffmpeg command line option; also you can set low/idle priority for ffmpeg process to minimize effect on other system's processes.

Comment: I am working with a asp.net core web app. It is still in development stage. The app allows users to upload videos. So, if compressing a single video uses 100% cpu and almost 5-10 minutes, then how long will it take for 10 videos(forget about hundred)?

Comment: @zackraiyan except very small clips, in general it is bad idea to convert video directly from MVC controller; instead of that, you can organize some queue and do that in background. Depending on the website load, this can be the same server (use low priority for ffmpeg process to keep web server responsive); for high-load you might need many servers for video processing.